# EF Core await ToArrayAsync() does not work in DbContext

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, entity-framework-core, thread-safety

```
public async Task<Asset[]> FindAssets()
{
    using (var ctx = new StockContext())
    {
        return await ctx.Assets.Where(x => x.Symbol == "TSLA").ToArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Please see above codes. When use `await` with `ToArrayAsync` in DbContext, it throw me runtime error `TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled`. and the stacktrace is shown as below:

```
TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, bool result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToArrayAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Can someone give me advice on how come it would be like that? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE FOR VERSION INFO**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-preview.4.20220.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0-preview.4.20220.10" />
```

Comment: Which version? You are aware that every version has very serious issues - they work on a lot of the mfor the upcoming 5.0 release in November, but before that you can choose your pain. Version is important here.

Comment: @TomTom I have updated the version, thank you for reminding

Comment: Ah, so an outdated 5.0 preview? I suggest you move to the nightly builds (preview 8 is now active - and yes, their release cycle is comically bad, they take ages to actually reelasea preview). This may be fixed in the nightlies - there is NO sense in discussing things on a preview codebase when your version is around 2 months or so outdated. Link the nightly builds.

Comment: Looks like a timeout connecting to the database

Comment: @PauloMorgado   No, Because it returns me this exception immediately